# How to generate icon for Google Play & iOS App Store in (1024 x 1024)

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

Does anyone have knowledge on how to create launcher icons at a resolution of 1024px by 1024px? Both the Google Play and iOS App Store require this new higher resolution.

Unfortunately, the maximum size for the internal image asset studio in Android Studio is 512px by 512px. How have others addressed this problem?

[image]

Comment: I designed this wizard in Android Studio and it generates what is needed for the Android Platform and Google Play. Apple has a requirement for 1024px icons, Google does not.  Google Play Store Hi-Res icon (512px), xxxhdpi Launcher icons (192px), Adaptive icon layer (108px). Where do you see a 1024px requirement for Android apps?

Comment: @JamalEason I'll be honest. I never expected an actual guy from google to respond to my answer. Nah its all good, I was trying to use Android studio to generate icons for IOS too since xcode doesn't have one.

Comment: @JamalEason P.S is it possible for you to give us an option to get rid of the transparent white space that comes with all icons generated? It makes the resulting app icons look smaller than the normal ones.

Comment: If you could file a feature request at our bug tracker here: ( https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html#how_to_report_a_bug) , that would be great. Please detail exactly what you want or the issue with the sizing of assets. Generally, the goal of the wizard is not to replace a full-blown image editor, however the transparent padding is aligned to the latest icon guidance here: https://material.io/guidelines/style/icons.html

Comment: @JamalEason So we should follow the guidance even though snapchat, instagram, and twitter don't? Common man, nobody reads that thing.

Comment: Where does your Asset Studio save the 512x512 px icon for the Play Store? I cannot find it in my project; all other icons have been generated (from a vector source).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think you can do that from android studio's asset studio.

Have you tried [appiconmaker](http://appiconmaker.co/). Just upload 1 icon and it will give you all the icons required for iOS and android in a zip file.

[This](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html) might help you as well.

Comment: Be better is there was a way to get Android Studio to generate the necessary files, but this works.